# TypeError: query Descriptors is not a numpy array, neither a scalar

Tags: python, opencv, sift

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import csv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# load image
img1 = cv2.imread('/Users/alisa/Desktop/sift.jpg',0)  # queryImage

img2 = cv2.imread('/Users/alisa/Desktop/siftt.jpg',0) # trainImage

# Initiate SIFT detector
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()

# find the keypoints and descriptors with SIFT
kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img2,None)

# read feature from file
with open('/Users/alisa/Desktop/q.csv') as csvDataFile:

    csvReader = csv.reader(csvDataFile)

    for gr_img1 in csvReader:

        des1=gr_img1

# Read keypoints from file
kp1 = []

lines = [line.strip() for line in open('/Users/alisa/Desktop/ali.txt')]

for line in lines:

    list = line.split(',')

    kps = cv2.KeyPoint(x=float(list[0]), y=float(list[1]), _size=float(list[2]), 

_angle=float(list[3]),

                               _response=float(list[4]), _octave=int(list[5]), 

_class_id=int(list[6]))

    kp1.append(kps)

# create BFMatcher object
bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)

# Match descriptors.
matches = bf.match(des1,des2)

# Sort them in the order of their distance.
matches = sorted(matches, key = lambda x:x.distance)

# Draw first 10 matches.
img3 = cv2.drawMatches(img1,kp1,img2,kp2,matches[:10],None, flags=2)

plt.imshow(img3),plt.show()
```

However, i get the following:

> TypeError: query Descriptors is not a numpy array, neither a scalar.

Can someone help me with this error?

Comment: What type is kp1 ? Check if it is an array. If not convert it to one

Comment: how can i convert kp1 to array?

Comment: `kp1_array = np.asarray(kp1)`

Comment: TypeError: queryDescriptors data type = 19 is not supported

Comment: now this error is occur.

Answer (score 0):

It is a common mistake. In your code, kp1 is a list not an array.

You can check with:
    type(kp1)

But drawMatches is expecting an numpy array.

You can simply:
    kp1 = np.asarray(kp1)

Comment: The OP has not responded. So we cannot conclude as yet.

Comment: TypeError: queryDescriptors data type = 19 is not supported

Comment: please put the files used somewhere we can download.

Comment: import cv3
import csv

img1 = cv2.imread("/Users/alisa/Desktop/sift.jpg")
gr_img1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(gr_img1, None)
filename = '/Users/alisa/Desktop/q.csv'
gr_img1 = ''
for row_features in des2:
    for feature in row_features:
        gr_img1 = gr_img1 + str(feature) + ','
    with open(filename, 'w+') as output:
        output.write(gr_img1 + "\n")

Comment: What I meant was for you to upload sift.jpg and q.csv somewhere.

Comment: send your email address